# Geometry nodes Controle point scale with z position

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to distribute points on my mesh but scale them so they get smaller the higher they get.

I think that we can do this by using a color ramp but I want to separate my position values and clamp the z value so I can properly use it.
For that, I would need a way to feed it into a separate XYZ node but I can't find a node that outputs the position per point to use it later.

This is my current state:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just need the fresh build of 2.93 alpha.

[image]

You can find **Attribute separate XYZ** here.

Comment: Thank you, will go right ahead and download it